# how to correct issue with uitabbar buttons overlap

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have an issue that pops up intermittently. The buttons on my tabbar overlap as shown in the screenshot. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?[image]

Comment: Hey, Did you find the solution for this? I am having same issue and Couldn't find the reason. It only happens when there is MORE tab in place. now sure whats going wrong. and also this is happening when changing the view controller stack of uitabviewcontroller.

Comment: No, I did not come up iwth a solution. But it seemed to go away by itself.

Comment: Are you using tabBarController?.title  in your project?

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and ended up using a container, with the button being in a parent view controller, which fixed my issue

or

You probably have to convert the recordButton.frame to the coordinate system of tabBarController.view.

just follow this link :

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView

Answer (score 0):

Please check the image size that you are using... I guess that is the issue.  Some images seems large thats why its overlapping

Answer (score 0):

1.U can change bgColor to check it, besure not overlap by some VC, or create tabbar twice when push/pop

2.besure removed item when change tabbar item, or just img overlap

3.upload key code will be helpful